# iOS Simulator Black Screen Issue Windows

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am having trouble with the iOS simulator and I was wondering if anyone else had the same problem or had any suggestions. I am very new to Xamarin; I just completed the Hello, World tutorial for iOS. I was able to build all with no errors. When I attempt to launch the app in the simulator, it displays a black screen.

[image]

I'm using an iMac running Parallels with Windows 10 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. I created a new Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) project under Cross-Platform. Using the latest XCODE (v 12.0) in iMac to get the simulators.

Main Interface in Info.plist is set to "(not set)". I tried changing it to LaunchScreen but still get the black screen.

[image]

[image]

I created a hello world project in xcode and it works fine. Black screen issue is on Windows side. Let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, whether you have connected to iMac from Windows side successfully? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, I have a successful connection.

Comment: Okey, you could open folder of **Resources** of iOS solution, to check whehter contains these launch screen image.https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvZV.png

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, I see them.

Comment: Okey, I'm not sure whehter it's related to the **Parallels**.  But if want to support iOS 14, you need to use Visual Studi 2019 to do. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run **[iOS 14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/get-started#download-and-install)**, you will need a **Visual Studio 2019** in PC.

> **Run Xcode 12** – Run Xcode 12 before updating and running Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio 2019, as it installs some tools that Xamarin requires.

And the Visual Stuido 2017 supports the last version is [iOS 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios12/get-started).

> **Run Xcode 10** – Run Xcode 10 before updating and running Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio 2017, as it installs some tools that Xamarin requires.